# Unique values in the past 12 months within a Groupby in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

How can I do a rolling 12M within a groupby and return the unique values (preferably in a list) for each row?

Currently I have a pandas dataframe like the following. I wish to group them by itemId, and replace the sellerId with a list of unique sellerIds within the last 12 months (based on effectiveDate). The effectiveDate is in a monthEnd format. Basically I would like to see for each itemId in each month, who are the unique sellerIds within the past 12 months window.

```
            itemId   sellerId   effectiveDate
    1975245 2585893  31280      2005-12-31
    1975246 2585893  31280      2006-02-28
    1975247 2585893  5407       2006-06-30
    1975248 2585893  5407       2006-08-31
    1975249 2585893  5407       2006-09-30
    1975250 2585893  5407       2006-11-30
    1975254 2585893  5407       2007-05-31
    1975257 2585893  5407       2007-06-30
    1975258 2585893  5407       2007-07-31
    1975259 2585893  5407       2008-03-31
    ...
```

I want to get it into something like the following:

```
            itemId  uniqueSellerIds effectiveDate
    1975245 2585893 [31280]         2005-12-31
    1975246 2585893 [31280]         2006-02-28
    1975247 2585893 [5407,31280]    2006-06-30
    1975248 2585893 [5407,31280]    2006-08-31
    ...
```

I have tried using groupby and then rolling methods, but it did not work. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `dt.year` ?

```
new_df = df.groupby([df["effectiveDate"].dt.year, df["itemId"]])["sellerId"].agg(list).to_frame()

print(new_df)
                                    sellerId
effectiveDate     itemId                      
2005              1975245 2585893  [31280]
2006              1975246 2585893  [31280]
                  1975247 2585893   [5407]
                  1975248 2585893   [5407]
                  1975249 2585893   [5407]
                  1975250 2585893   [5407]
2007              1975254 2585893   [5407]
                  1975257 2585893   [5407]
                  1975258 2585893   [5407]
2008              1975259 2585893   [5407]
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified the original DataFrame to this:

```
    itemId          sellerId   effectiveDate
    19752572585893  31280      2005-12-31
    19752572585893  31280      2006-02-28
    19752592585894  31280      2008-01-31
    19752592585894  5407       2007-07-31
    19752592585894  5407       2008-03-31
    19752592585894  5407       2008-01-31
```

From there I filtered it down to have just the most recent year for each `itemId`:

```
df['effectiveDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['effectiveDate'])
filtered = df[df.groupby(by=['itemId']).apply(lambda g: 
                                              g['effectiveDate'] >= 
                                              g['effectiveDate'].max() - 
                                              pd.Timedelta(days=365)).values]
```

Then I combined the `sellerId`s like this:

```
filtered.groupby(by=['itemId'])['sellerId'].agg(lambda x: x.unique().tolist())
```

And what's left is to get the maximum dates and join it back to the filtered and combined data:

```
max_dates = filtered.groupby(by=['itemId'])['effectiveDate'].max()
modified_df = pd.concat([compressed,max_dates],axis=1)
```

Result:

```
                     sellerId effectiveDate
itemId                                     
19752572585893        [31280]    2006-02-28
19752592585894  [31280, 5407]    2008-03-31
```